# Помогите разобраться с make и CLion

Tags: makefile, clion

Имеется вопросик касаемо make. Я достаточно часто слышу слово *фронтенд* вне web'а. Кто может пояснить мне, что это? Make — система сборки файлов. Как я понял, она помогает кратко выполнять рутинные действия по компиляции. Это верно?

Я юзаю CLion для C-программирования, и одна вещь мне непонятна. Можно использовать make для дебаггинга и компиляции, но создаются лишние файлы. Я бы мог просто выполнять набор команд в консоли (и такая возможность есть!), но тогда CLion думает почему-то, что я пишу на C++ (хотя файл .C) и поэтому некорректно подсвечивает текст. Что делать?

Comment: *"хотя файл .C"* Вот прямо капсом? Попробуйте маленькую букву. *"создаются лишние файлы"* Какие? *"помогает кратко выполнять рутинные действия по компиляции"* Да. *"часто слышу слово фронтенд вне web'а"* Можно пример конкретной фразы?

Comment: 1) Нет, конечно, пишу строчную букву.
2) Папка .idea с непонятными и, кажется мне,ненужными файлам
3) С хабра: "При этом сама CMake непосредственно сборкой не занимается, а представляет из себя front-end. В качестве back-end`a могут выступать различные версии make и Ninja". Да, это про Cmake, но в других контекстах также слышал

Comment: А конкретно код который clion воспринимает как с++ показать можете?

Comment: В панели вариантов дополнения кода отсутствует `stdio.h`, и, если использовать функцию `printf`, выведет предупредительное сообщение типа: "Откуда взял? Подключи `stdio.h!`". Это странно... А компилируется через консоль нормально.

А если подключить к проекту CMake, всё работает.

Comment: Насколько я помню, clion не дополняет код включаемых файлов, а то что происходит у вас скорее всего неправильно настроено рабочее окружение. Которое при работе с cmake, настраивается автоматически.

Comment: *"Папка .idea"* А внутри что? На счет frontend/backend - тут вроде из контекста понятно. CMake взаимодействует с пользователем (в том смысле что он читает написанные вами cmake-файлы). А сам процесс сборки он делегирует make/ninja/...

Comment: Я понимаю, что эти файлы нужны. Но не нуждаюсьв CMake — компилируюпросто через консоль, но в этом случае дебаддинг некорректен.